# Checking to see if Gtk mainloop is running

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygobject

Is there a way that I can check to see if the Gtk.main() loop is alive? Similar to the threading.is_alive() function? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Gtk.main_level()` function](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/functions.html#Gtk.main_level):

```
 Gtk.main_level()
    Returns:    the nesting level of the current invocation of the main loop
```

In other words, a return value of 0 means no mainloop is running.